# Get my 4G router Huawei e5172 to work on battery power

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, router

I have a Huawei LTE CPE e5172 4G router, the router have a little spot in the back for battery connection, so I went ahead and purchased a battery pack for it. The battery is charging, and there is even a battery indicator on the router web page (192.168.1.1). When unplugged the router is still working, the network bars are on, but no internet connectivity (Ethernet or Wifi). I have tried to going through the properties and reading the [manual](http://setuprouter.com/router/huawei/e5172s-920/manual-1260.pdf), but no luck.

Can somebody provide additional information on this subject? How just to tell me how to turn on the Wifi when on battery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Aliexpress.com page for the battery says [battery back-up for phone calls](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Huawei-E5172-Rechargeable-Battery/1050198_32240334782.html) (which would use the TEL RJ-11).

Can't help but think 3.6V 1500 mah is a bit light for powering WiFi.

Looking a little harder you can refer to the [Product Description](http://www.3grouterstore.co.uk/3G/HUAWEI-E5172As-22-LTE-CPE-Product-Description.pdf) (See PDF page 14 (Page 6)):

[image: battery.png]

And that specifies the battery is only for the voice connection.